# Llamar a una funcion dentro de un objeto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo, donde estoy intentando desde JS acceder a la funcion `calculateAge` en JS pero se imprime un Undefined por consola. Es por el scope? Como podria acceder a esa funcion?

```
<script>
var gonzalo={
    firstName:'Gonzalo',
    lastName:'De Genaro',
    job: 'teacher',
    birthDay: 1978,
    family:['Romina','Nilda','Sergio'],
    isMarried: false,
    calculateAge: function(){
        this.age= 2020-this.birthDay; //AQUI THIS.AGE GUARDAMOS EL RESULTADO DEL 2020-THIS.BIRTHDAY
    }
}


console.log(gonzalo.job);

console.log(gonzalo.calculateAge()); //*EN ESTA LINEA NO LLAMA AL METODO*

console.log(gonzalo);
```

Answer (score 2):

lo unico que tienes que hacer es retornar tu funcion y listo ya que no haces ninguna funcion dentro de ella;

```
var gonzalo={
    firstName:'Gonzalo',
    lastName:'De Genaro',
    job: 'teacher',
    birthDay: 1978,
    family:['Romina','Nilda','Sergio'],
    isMarried: false,
    calculateAge: function(){
       return this.age= 2020-this.birthDay;

    }
}

console.log(gonzalo.calculateAge())
```

si te fijas dentro de la funcion hay una palabra nueva: `return`

```js
var gonzalo={
    firstName:'Gonzalo',
    lastName:'De Genaro',
    job: 'teacher',
    birthDay: 1978,
    family:['Romina','Nilda','Sergio'],
    isMarried: false,
    calculateAge: function(){
       return this.age= 2020-this.birthDay;
        
    }
}
console.log(gonzalo.calculateAge()); 
alert(gonzalo.calculateAge())
```

Comment: Pero en su código no quiere devolver un valor, sino asignarlo a una propiedad del propio objeto. El método no necesita devolver un valor. Luego comprueba el objeto y no se ve la propiedad que quiere asignar (me da que el fallo es que no ha creado la propiedad antes en el objeto)

Comment: @Jakala entonces, como seria el codigo para vos?

Comment: @Jakala El undefined resulta porque la función no devuelve nada. Esta respuesta asigna el valor **y** lo devuelve, cumple con lo que quiere el OP

Comment: precisamente por eso. Si esta utilizando un metodo tipo setter, y su logica es solo settear el valor, el metodo no tiene por que devolver nada. Simplemente es que esta llamando a un metodo que no tiene que devolver nada. El codigo sigue siendo correcto. Quizas el problema es que llama a un metodo que NO tiene que devolver valor. Lo explico en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas lo siguiente:

- Agregar un `return` a la función para que de este modo sepa que debe entregar el resultado de la lógica que contiene dentro, como no lo tiene y haces esot: `variable.propiedad()` intentas obtener el resultado del proceso de la misma pero carece de la instrucción que retorne algo por eso da `undefined`
- Agrega en el llamado una sintaxis de esta forma: `variable.propiedad()`
- Si solo haces esto: `variable.propiedad` te va a devolver el cuerpo de la función es decir el contenido de esta.

Por lo tanto tu código debería verse así:

```js
    var gonzalo={
        firstName:'Gonzalo',
        lastName:'De Genaro',
        job: 'teacher',
        birthDay: 1978,
        family:['Romina','Nilda','Sergio'],
        isMarried: false,
        calculateAge: function(){
            return this.age= 2020-this.birthDay; //AQUI THIS.AGE GUARDAMOS EL RESULTADO DEL 2020-THIS.BIRTHDAY
        }
    }
    console.log(gonzalo.calculateAge());
```

Answer (score 0):

Considero que tu código original, como tal, es correcto.

El asunto es que has definido un método tipo setter, el cual **no** retorna valor. Por lo que conceptualmente **no** tiene sentido llamarlo **y** obtener valor.

si haces:

```
var gonzalo = {}; 
var gonzalo={ 
  age: 0, 
  firstName:'Gonzalo', 
  lastName:'De Genaro', 
  job: 'teacher', 
  birthDay: 1978, 
  family:['Romina','Nilda','Sergio'], 
  isMarried: false, 
  calculateAge: function(){ 
    this.age= 2020-this.birthDay; } 
} 

console.log(gonzalo.age); 
gonzalo.calculateAge(); //llamas a un metodo setter, que no devuelve valor
console.log(gonzalo.age);
```

veras que el primer valor es 0 (te lo inicializo en el objeto), luego llamamos a tu metodo setter(que calcula el valor) y luego si accedes a la propiedad, tienes el valor correcto.

otra cosa seria que tuvieras un metodo **getter**. entonces ahí si tienes que tener un return en tu metodo:

```
var gonzalo={ 
  age: 0, 
  firstName:'Gonzalo', 
  lastName:'De Genaro', 
  job: 'teacher', 
  birthDay: 1978, 
  family:['Romina','Nilda','Sergio'], 
  isMarried: false, 
  calculateAge: function(){ 
    this.age= 2020-this.birthDay; } 
  getAge: function() {
     return this.age; }
}
```

ahi si podrias hacer:

```
console.log(gonzalo.age); 
gonzalo.calculateAge(); //llamas a un metodo setter, que no devuelve valor
console.log(gonzalo.getAge());
```

En tu caso que es más un problema de OO, que de código en si.